# Auto Unlock on Mac doesn't work if iPhone is in range

Tags: iphone, mac, security, apple-watch, password

For some odd reason Auto Unlock on my Mac doesn't work unless my iPhone is out of range, in Airplane Mode, or off. I just discovered this because it worked for the first time when my iPhone was rebooting due to an update. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things but what seemed to help the most was toggling AirDrop on my mac from "Everyone" to "No One" and then to "Contacts Only".